# How can I start a timed task in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

**Scene:** I'm working on a website which display summary data analysed from mongodb, and the count documents in mongo is too huge that every api takes 15 seconds around, which is too slow. So I wanna cache the analysed result in mongodb, and everytime I need to fetch the data, I fetch them from the "cache".
**question:** Can I just fetch the api in _app.tsx like the codes below? I feel it wired to start the task in client side, but I'm not sure where is wired.
fetch the api in useCache:

```
const useCache = (time?: number) => {
  const _time = time ?? 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000  // default 6 hours
  const startTiming = () => {
    return setInterval(() => {
      fetch('/api/cache')
    }, _time)
  }

  /**
   * @param id interval id
   */
  const stopTiming = (id: string) => {
    clearInterval(id)
  }

  return [startTiming, stopTiming] as const
}

export default useCache
```

After page mounted, set interval and fetch the api; while page unmounted, clear the interval:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  const [startTiming, stopTiming] = useCache()

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = startTiming()

    return () => {
      console.log('delete id:', id)
      stopTiming(id as any)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi @sheepeer, I would say that your application will perform better if you move that logic to the server side...keep your frontend application as simple as possible

Comment: @lissettdm Thx for your suggestion ! ! I finally removed the codes in _app.tsx and, instead I fetch the api in next.config.js with node-cron. Is the best practice fetching the api in another server rather than what I did? (I do always do too many things in frontend, since I'm not familiar with backend... It's time to study for me o_o)